# Effect of a mistaken limit order on market price

Tags: limit-order

If a sell limit order for a very small volume was entered mistakenly at a very low price, would it get executed and would it affect the market price ?

eg:

The current market price for FOO is $500 USD, I mistakenly enter a sell limit order for $5 for a very small quantity, will it be executed or will it be cancelled by the exchange (in general, not exchange specific)?

If it is executed, will the market price reflect $5?

Answer (score 8):

There is no effect.

Given that the last price is $500, there should be existing bid/ask orders creating a reasonable spread. For example, bid is $499 and ask is $501.

Any limit order to sell entered at price below $499 will be executed at $499.

In other words, even if you entered $5, it will be sold at $499. That is unless you are selling huge amount of outstanding shares.

This is called first-mover disadvantage.

Comment: Indeed, the exchange is *required* to execute sales against higher bids first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you point me to a resource that backs it up for further reading?

Comment: The order may even be cancelled as some exchange have a range from the current price where orders can be entered.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinnes: The SEC has articles about these rules. See for example [**Best Execution Requirement**](http://www.sec.gov/answers/bestex.htm).

Comment: To be honest this issue is both exchange specific and broker specific. An example is http://www1.nyse.com/pdfs/CEE_Policies_Email_Submission_Guidelines.pdf